# When scroll in Recyler View Radio Button changes its selection

Tags: android

I am using RecylerView to set RadioButton.But on selection selected changes its position when scroll.Please help me.

```
Thanx in advance!!!
```

My RecylerView Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dummy_recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My RadioButton Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_dummy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My RecylerView Java File

```
public class Dummy extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> arr_qty;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dummy);
        arr_qty=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0;i<50;i++){
            arr_qty.add(String.valueOf(i));

        }
        RecyclerView dummy = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.dummy_recycle);
        DummyAdapter adapter = new DummyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arr_qty);
        dummy.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        dummy.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My RecylerView Adapter

```
public class DummyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DummyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Context c;
    ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<>();
    public DummyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arr_qty) {
        this.arr = arr_qty;
        this.c = context;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.dummy_value, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arr.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public RadioButton radio;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            radio = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_dummy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to create one model class with getter setter and in that you have to store on checked radiobutton id.because when we scroll listview it just remove data and store new data in view.which we can see on screen.

Comment: Can you please explain through coding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Recycleview adapter you can add the below the line. It's already working in my code. This code helps to fix your list position.

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest way. Others are suggesting setting tags and all. Thanks.

Comment: working excellent, as what i want .. thanks man "save my day"